# Remove item from ListView with onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I have a ListView where there are all the applications installed on the device. At the click on the item, part of the uninstall. So far everything works fine, the problem is that once the application is uninstalled, then it is no longer on the device, it remains in the list. Obviously this is not good and therefore I wrote this code to try to remove it once it has been uninstalled.

```
myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            { 
            int requestCode = 1;
                app = appInfoArrayList.get(position);
                Uri packageUri = Uri.parse("package:"+app.packagename);
                Intent uninstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, packageUri);
                startActivityForResult(uninstallIntent, requestCode);
            }

    });   

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {

        String msg = "MyApp: ";
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == 1)
            {

                 try {
                     packageInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(app.packagename, 0);
                 }
                 catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                     Log.v("Catch",msg );          
                     appInfoArrayList.remove(position);
                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
                 }

                }

            else {

            }

            Log.v(msg, String.valueOf(resultCode)+", "+String.valueOf(requestCode));

    }
```

In the LogCat i read: MyApp: Catch 0 (resultCode) , 1 (requestCode) So this means that enters correctly in the catch, but despite this, even if the application has been uninstalled is still on the list. Ideas on how I can fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried your_list.remove(position_of_item) then notify notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: `appInfoArrayList.remove(position);` where you are assigning value to `position` variable? I can't seem to find it in your code.

Comment: Hello, sorry I forgot to write that the variable int position is declared outside of methods.

Comment: That's fine..are you updating the `position` when the item is clicked inside `onItemClick`?Something like `this.position = position`